# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: when trying to upload folder

Tags: selenium

I need to upload a folder, but selenium thinks I want to upload a file. I have verified that a folder exists in this location, but the selenium error is about a file not being found.

If I change the directory to `./././resources/test_folder/txt.txt` it works fine, but I don't need to upload just a file, I need to upload a folder with a file inside it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

code (python):

```
path = os.path.abspath('./././resources/test_folder/')
upload_element = context.tools.driver.find_element_by_id('folder-input')
upload_element.send_keys(path)
```

error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: {...}/resources/test_folder
```

Comment: How does your application look when it wants the folder to be uploaded? is it a classic uplaod window? is it an in-browser path?   - I'm wondering is there a way to go old-school and use auto-it to drive the OS to deliver the folder to the browser?

Comment: The application has link which opens the os file browser and expects the user to select a folder. What is auto-it?
I'm using a mac btw.